# How to find the sum of factorial of all numbers in a series?

Tags: java, bluej

I want to create a program to find the sum of factorial of all numbers in a series till 20. 
I have to find 's' in s = 1 + (1*2) + (1*2*3) + ...(1*2*3...20).
I tried a program but it is not working. I am using BlueJ IDE.

```
int a =1; 
    int s = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        while (i >0)
        {

            a = a * i;
            i--;
        }
        s = s+a;
    }
    System.out.println(s);
```

The compiler does not show any error message but when I run the program the JVM(Java Virtual Machine) keeps loading and the output screen does not show up.

Comment: Use a different variable for your inner loop.  Your outer loop is trying to increment `i` but your inner loop in decrementing it

Comment: Your while loop is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one :

```
 public class Main 
 {
 public static void main (String[]args)
 {
  int fact = 1;
  int sum = 0;
  int i, j = 1;
  for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
  {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
      fact = fact * j;
  }
  sum += fact;
  System.out.println ("sum = " + sum);
  fact = 1;
  }
 }
}
```

Always give proper variable name and Try to avoid to use same variable at different places i.e you have use variable i in outer and inner loop which is not good habit.

Comment: Thanks, the program does work, but i wanted to ask why u have initialized 'fact' again after the inner loop ?

Comment: Because after every iteration fact hold the factorial value of particular number and if we find the factorial for next number then we have to start with value 1.

Comment: @Tausif are you _sure_ on that. Can you see a way to find the factorial for the next number _without_ an inner loop?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a different loop variable name in your inner loop, and you also need to use a `long` to store your sum. In fact, I would first write a method to multiply up to a number in the series. Like,

```
static long multiplyTo(int n) {
    long r = 1L;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        r *= i;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Then you can invoke that and calculate your sum with a simple loop. Like,

```
long sum = 0L;
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    sum += multiplyTo(i);
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

I get

```
2561327494111820313
```

Comment: Whilst this fixes the OP’s problem - the real answer here is that the inner loop isn’t needed at all...

Answer (score 0):

Using streams:

```
    long s = LongStream.rangeClosed(1, 20)
        .map(upper -> LongStream.rangeClosed(1, upper)
            .reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b))
        .sum();
    System.out.println(s);
```

Prints `2561327494111820313`

Comment: This calculates the factorial every “step” which is completely pointless. Whilst a cute one liner, it is hugely inefficient and is akin to iterating by index on a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same program using Scanner Class

```
import java.util.*;
class Sum_Factorial
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i; //Denotes Integer
        int n; //Denotes Number
        int f=1; //Denotes Factorial
        int s=0; //Denotes Sum
        System.out.println("Enter the value of N : ");
        n=in.nextInt();
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            f=f*i;
            s=s+f;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of the factorial numbers is "+s);
    }
}
```